# What are the curly braces in "&{ s }.borrow_self()" for?

Tags: rust

I'm going through the [statements and expressions chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html#block-expressions) in the Rust book. What are the curly braces in `&{ s }.borrow_self()` for?
Am I getting the pointer, and if so would it not make more sense to use `&s.borrow_self()`?

Just a little confused as to what purpose the curly braces have and the logic behind using them.

```
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    struct Struct;

    impl Struct {
        fn consume_self(self) {}
        fn borrow_self(&self) {}
    }

    fn move_by_block_expression() {
        let s = Struct;

        // Move the value out of `s` in the block expression.
        (&{ s }).borrow_self();

        // Fails to execute because `s` is moved out of.
        s.consume_self();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{}` creates a new scope. Remember that the last statement in each scope is used as the return value. In this case `{s}` evaluates to `s`. So `&{s}` moves `s` into the scope, returns it, and then just references it.

Let's evaluate "manually":

1. `(&{s}).borrow_self()` => Move `s` to the new scope and return it.
2. `(&s).borrow_self()` => Reference `s`
3. `Struct::borrow_self(&s)` => Evaluate method over `&self` (`&s`)

Comment: This was an awesome answer thank you Netwave. Can I ask, why I would need to move 's' out of scope first. Could you not just use the example number 2 that you have put?

Comment: @AHBensiali, there is no reason to move it. They just did it to illustrate the example.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the linked page from the reference:

> This can be used to force moving a value if really needed. For example, the following example fails on the call to `consume_self` because the struct was moved out of `s` in the block expression.

So:

- In general, curly braces can be used when something needs to be moved for the code to be correct.
- In this example, their usage is explicitly stated to be incorrect. The valid code would contain just `s.borrow_self()`, as you've found out.
- The value of this example is in providing the case when the move semantics are immediately obvious. It doesn't have to be useful as a code, since the quoted book is language reference, and it's more important for it to clearly show the expected semantics then to educate on "how the code should be written".